# Create a potocol handler for a Powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I create a protocol handler for a powershell script and make the target powershell script receive command line arguments?

And what are the security concerns in doing so?

Answer (score 6):

I thought I write up a decent guide on doing so since the information I found online was lacking some details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)

**First off the security concerns**

1. Any program, website, script etc. that is running on your computer can set off the protocol. There are no authorization checks.
2. You should NOT create a universal protocol handler. That would be a massive security issue concern. I mean that would enable a program, website, script etc. to run any powershell script or command on your computer.

**Creating the protocol handler in Windows registry**
The protocol must be registered in Windows Registry. It's a simple task.

***I'm calling my powershell protocol handler for `pwsh`***

**Step 1:** Open the Registry Editor and navigate to
`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`

For inspiration you can look at `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http` to look at how that protocol handler is made.

**Step 2:** Create the following hierarchy:

Create the key `pwsh`: `[Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pwsh]`

Edit the default value of `(Default)` to `URL:pwsh`. Remember I call my protocol handler for `pwsh`, write whatever your is called.

Add a string value with the name `URL Protocol` and empty data.

It should look like this now:
[image: Registry entry for pwsh]

Create a new key under `pwsh`, `DefaultIcon`: `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pwsh\DefaultIcon`.
Set the `(Default)` data field to a filepath that leads to an icon or image. I used the powershell icon for Powershell 7 `C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell\7-preview\assets\ps_black_32x32.ico`.

Then create the keys `shell` -> `open` -> `command` like shown on the image above.

In the key `command` change the `(Default)` data value to where powershell is installed and then the powershell script to be run.

When testing I do this: `"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.exe" -noexit -executionpolicy bypass -Command {Write-Host %1}`
***Note I am using powershell core 6 and your path to powershell is probably different.***
You can test to check if it works by opening the `run` program in Windows(Windows+R).

[image: Run program with the protocol]

Expected behavior is the powershell window to open with the text `pwsh:Hello Stackoverflow` printed.

[image: Powershell printing out text]

**Step 3:** Create a powershell script to handle incoming actions on the protocol.
The production ready data value for the `command` key: `"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.exe" -noexit -File C:\handleActions.ps1 %1`

```
Param($Argument="") # If the protocol is ran you always at least get the protocol name as an argument. (if using the %1)
[String]
$Argument 

function Handle-Actions { # The cmdlet 'Handle-Actions' uses an unapproved verb. 
    [cmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=0)]
        [String]
        $Argument 
    )
    $Argumuments = $Argument.Split([Char]0x003F) # Splits by `?`
    #Argumnets is now in an array, do whatever you need to next.
    $Argumuments | %{
        Write-Host $_ # Writes each argument that was seperated by ? to a line
    }
}

Handle-Actions -Argument $Argument
```

Given the run command `pwsh:?firstArgument?SecondArgument` the script will output:

```
pwsh:
firstArgument
SecondArgument
```

Comment: Nicely done. Note that if you want to emulate query-string syntax for passing arguments you should use `pwsh:?firstArgument&SecondArgument` instead, but this syntax isn't strictly necessary; if you do use it, it's best to parse the query string with `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString()`. Note that the `[String] $Argument` part of your handler script has no effect (a type-constrained parameter variable needs to be inside the `param(...)` block).

Answer (score 6):

To complement [your helpful guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58579375/45375) with **sample code that automates creation of a custom protocol handler**:

The following:

- Creates a custom URI protocol `custom:` (rather than `pwsh:`, given that PowerShell is simply used to *implement* the protocol) to which an open-ended number of arguments can be passed.
- Does so for the *current user only* (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`) by default; however, it's easy to tweak the code to implement the custom protocol  for *all* users instead (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`), though you'll need to run the code *with elevation* (as administrator) then.

  - A handler `*.ps1` script is automatically created:

    - At `$env:USERPROFILE\customUriHandler.ps1` in the current-user scenario.
    - At `$env:ALLUSERPROFILE\customUriHandler.ps1` in the all-users scenario.
  - The handler script simply echoes the arguments passed to it, and it is invoked in a PowerShell script window that is kept *open* after script execution (`-NoExit`); tweak the PowerShell command as needed.
- The protocol expects its arguments as if it were a *shell command*, i.e., as a *space-separated* list of arguments, with argument-individual `"..."` quoting, if necessary.

  - The sample command at the end uses `Start-Process` to invoke the following URI, which you could also submit from the `Run` dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>), which passes arguments `one`, `two & three`, `four`:

    - URI: `custom:one "two & three" four`
    - Invocation via `Start-Process`: `Start-Process 'custom:one "two & three" four'`
  - *Caveat*: If you submit this URI via a *web browser*'s address bar (note: doesn't seem to work with Microsoft Edge), it is URI-escaped, and a single `one%20%22two%20&%20three%22%20four` argument is passed instead, which would require custom parsing; similarly, submitting from File Explorer's address bar passes `one%20two%20&%20three%20four`, though note that the `"` chars. are - curiously - lost in the process.

```
# Determine the scope:
# Set to $false to install machine-wide (for all users)
# Note: Doing so then requires running with ELEVATION.
$currentUserOnly = $true

if (-not $currentUserOnly) {
  net session *>$null
  if ($LASTEXITCODE) { Throw "You must run this script as administrator (elevated)." }
}

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# The name of the new protocol scheme
$schemeName = 'custom'

$pwshPathEscaped = (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path -replace '\\', '\\'

$handlerScript = ($env:ALLUSERSPROFILE, $env:USERPROFILE)[$currentUserOnly] + "\${schemeName}UriHandler.ps1"
$handlerScriptEscaped = $handlerScript -replace '\\', '\\'

# Create the protocol handler script.
@'

# Remove the protocol scheme name from the 1st argument.
$argArray = $args.Clone()
$argArray[0] = $argArray[0] -replace '^[^:]+:'
# If the 1st argument is now empty, remove it.
if ('' -eq $argArray[0]) { $argArray = $argArray[1..($argArray.Count-1)] }

"Received $($argArray.Count) argument(s)."

$i = 0
foreach ($arg in $argArray) {
  "#$((++$i)): [$arg]"
}

'@ > $handlerScript

# Construct a temp. *.reg file.
# Target the scope-appropriate root registrykey.
$rootKey = ('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes', 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes')[$currentUserOnly]
# Determine a temp. file path.
$tempFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempPath() + [IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName() + '.reg'
@"
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[$rootKey\$schemeName]
@="URL:$schemeName"
"URL Protocol"=""

[$rootKey\$schemeName\DefaultIcon]
@="$pwshPathEscaped"

[$rootKey\$schemeName\shell]
@="open"

[$rootKey\$schemeName\shell\open\command]
; === Tweak the PowerShell command line here: ===
@="\"$pwshPathEscaped\" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoExit -File \"$handlerScriptEscaped\" %1"

"@ > $tempFile

# Import the *.reg file into the registry.
& {
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
  reg.exe import $tempFile 2>$null
  if ($LASTEXITCODE) { Throw "Importing with reg.exe failed: $tempFile"}
}

# Remove the temp. *.reg file.
Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath $tempFile

# ---

# Sample invocation of the new protocol with 3 arguments:
$uri = "$schemeName`:one `"two & three`" four"
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Invoking the following URI: $uri"
Start-Process $uri
```

Comment: @xdhmoore; That's indeed what it was, thanks for letting me know - answer updated.